agregar un key y un value a un objeto, a partir de dos strings que son los parámetros de mi función
Necesito hacer una función que acepte 3 parámetros, un objeto y dos strings. La función debe de agregar el key con su valor indicados en los dos strings, el primer string será el nombre del key y el segundo su valor.
aquí esta el código de lo que he hecho:
function addPropertie(object,key,value){
 object.key=value;
 console.log(object);
}
const obj={edad:"39",altura:"1.8m"};
addPropertie(obj,"ocupación","musico");

//Esto es lo que genera//
{
"edad": "39",
"altura": "1.8m",
"key": "musico"
}
// no se como hacer para que el key tome el parametro que le estoy poniendo a la función

Existen al menos 2 maneras:
1) Tratando el objeto como un diccionario
Es casi lo mismo que tienes tu, pero en lugar de utilizar el punto se utiliza corchetes []


function addPropertie(object,key,value){
 object[key]=value;
}
const obj={edad:"39",altura:"1.8m"};
addPropertie(obj,"ocupación","musico");
console.log(obj);



2) Usando defineProperty
Esta opción es más versátil, permite establecer el comportamiento de la nueva propiedad, principalmente su nivel de acceso (si se puede cambiar el valor o listar)


function addPropertie(object,key,value){
  Object.defineProperty(object, key, {
    value: value,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
  });
}
const obj={edad:"39",altura:"1.8m"};
addPropertie(obj,"ocupación","musico");
console.log(obj);



